# VISA Generate CDOL2

Tags: emv

I tried to import transaction status (CDOL2) to VISA card.

I send all expected tags

[91, 8A, 95, 9F37, 9F4C]

and values

[8A0230309108A5E6BB0D00860000, 000, 8080008000, BE66ABE7, 00]

but card refused transaction.

what could be the problem?

Maybe problem in tag 9F4C value 00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem looks more like issue with 91 and 8A.
The value you show as 91 is certainly not the one you are sending as it looks like TLV encoded where in fact you can see inside both the real value of 91 as and the correct value of 8A (which should be ISO8583:87 response code that was sent by issuer in the authorization response, not the value that terminal has received in its interface with device handler).